# $G =\{z\in \mathbb{C}: z^n =1\}\leq (\mathbb{C} -\{0\}, \times) \wedge \exists g\in G: |G| = |\left \langle {g} \right \rangle| = n. $

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

may I verify if my proof to the a/m claim is correct?  Thank you.

Lemma: Let $G$ be a finite group. $|\{x \in G: x^m =e\}|\leq m$ $\Longleftrightarrow G$ is cyclic.

Proof: 
Suppose $|\{x \in G: x^m =e\}|\leq m.$

Consider any $y\in G$ such that $o(y) =m$. Since  $ \left| { \left\{ x  \in G: x^m =e\right\}  } \right| \leq m $ and $ \left| \left \langle {y}\right \rangle \right| =m $, we must have $ \left \langle {y}\right \rangle = \left\{ x \in G: x^m=e \right\} $. Hence, given any $z \neq y \in G$ such that $o(z)=o(y)=m,$ it follows that $ \left \langle {z}\right \rangle =  \left \langle {y}\right \rangle$ and $z$ generates $\left \langle {y}\right \rangle $

Let $n  =  \left| G \right| .$ Given $m \in \mathbb{N} - \left\{n\right\} $ such that $m|n$,  choose(if any) $x_m\in G$ such that $o(x_m) =m$. 
Suppose $G$ is not cyclic. 
$n = \sum_{m|n,m\neq n } \left| \left\{ y \in G: o(y)=m \right\} \right|$ 
$ \leq \sum_{m|n,m\neq n }$ {# generators of $  \left \langle {x_m}\right \rangle $, where $o(x_m)=m$} $= \sum_{m|n,m\neq n } \varphi (m)$ $<  \sum_{m|n } \varphi (m) = n.$     This is a contradiction.

Conversely, if $|G| = |\left \langle {g} \right \rangle| = n,$ let $d=gcd(m,n).$ Then $|\{x \in G: x^m =e\}| = |\left \langle {g^{\frac{n}{d}}} \right \rangle| = d \leq m. $

Now, the proof that $G =\{z\in \mathbb{C}: z^n =1\}\leq (\mathbb{C} -\{0\}, \times)$ is routine. Suppose $|G| > n,$ then $z^{n} -1 = (z-g)(z-g^2)...(z-g^n)h(z), $ where $deg(h(z)) \geq 1.$ This means $deg(RHS)= n $ $ \neq deg(LHS) > n.$ Contradiction.

So, $|G| \leq n$ and 
by lemma, $G = \left \langle {g} \right \rangle,$ for some $g\in G.$ Clearly, $o(g) \leq n.$ Suppose $o(g) = r<n.$ Then, $z^{n} -1 = (z-g)(z-g^2)...(z-g^{r-1})(z-1) $ and $deg(LHS) = n \neq deg(RHS) = r.$ Contradiction.

Comment: In the first case, you are already assuming $G$ is cyclic since otherwise, you don't know if an element of order $m$ exists. Consider the dihedral group of $2n$ elements. Then any element raised to the $2n$ power will be the identity, thus on the left-hand side you get the cardinality of the group, while on the right you get the cardinality of the group. This, the first hypothesis is satisfied, but the conclusion is not satisfied.

Comment: what is $m$ in your proof ? is it quantified universally or existentially ? or is it the order of the group ?

Comment: Hi, I have made the necessary amendments!